# html from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want  to insert html with a few controls +style  from the code behind ( asp.net c#) how  can I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` then add controls to this.

e.g.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "/someurl.jpg";
img.CssClass = "someclass";
img.ID = "someid";
img.AlternateText = "alttext"

PlageHolderId.Controls.Add(img);
```

This would produce the html

```
<img src="/someurl.jpg" class="someclass" id="someid" alt="alttext" />
```

You can then do this will any control, literal, hyperlink, button, table, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<asp:Literal>` controls in the markup, then set their `Text`s in code-behind.
Make sure to set `Mode="PassThrough"` to prevent them from escaping the HTML.

You can add server-side controls by adding them to the `Controls` collection of any existing control (such as an `<asp:Panel>`)

Comment: and then Literal. Because I want Every time Other litral ?

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

Add a few `<asp:PlaceHolder>`'s to your template file in the `<head>` and `<body>`

Then use `PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add();`

Comment: PlaceHolder: Stores dynamically added server controls on the Web page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I put a `<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server"/>` , and in the codebehind i add controls with:

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(...)
```

If you want to insert HTML code direct to the panel, use

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Your HTML goes here!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Literal control you can use either HtmlGenericControl

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl();
div.ID = "div";
div.TagName = "div";
div.Attributes["class"] = "container";
form1.Controls.Add(div);
```